# How to position an image on top of another image within the bottom image's dimensions?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a gallery style layout for a portfolio of projects. This is all done with Bootstrap 3.

On desktop screen-sizes (md and lg in Bootstrap terms) I use 4 columns. On tablet screen-sizes (sm) I'm using two columns and on mobile screen-sizes I'm using 1 column.

Every project in the gallery has a title, a short excerpt and an image thumbnail. For each project I place all of this stuff inside of a widget area.

The main problem is with the thumbnail image. The designer had the idea to place the thumbnail for each project inside of an iMac monitor image. To make that a bit more complex the black border of the iMac monitor is sticking out of the widget area.

Because a picture says more than just words here's a small example:

[image: what i want to achieve]

I'm having trouble positioning the actual thumbnail picture within the iMac image so it stays inside of the gray area of the iMac image even when I resize the screen and when we reach breakpoints of the Bootstrap grid.

I've made an isolated fiddle of what I've been trying so far: http://jsfiddle.net/9ek3eqmv/

The html for each project element in the gallery looks like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 project-widget-container">

        <div class="project-widget-wrap" style="border: 1px solid green">

            <div class="project-widget">

                <div class="project-title">
                    <h4>Project 2</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="project-excerpt">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                </div>

                <!--<div class="project-thumbnail-placeholder"></div>-->

            </div>

            <div class="project-image-container">
                <img class="imac img-responsive" src="http://s29.postimg.org/b5kegwt53/small_mac.png">
                <img class="featured-image img-responsive" src="http://s29.postimg.org/ryb2fc5tz/test_2.jpg">
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

I made a class .project-widget-wrap to get the imac sticking out effect. This is just a wrapper with the padding for the black border of the iMac image:

```
.project-widget-wrap {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        position: relative;
    }
```

Within that element I have the .project-widget class div to get the white widget background and to contain the other elements.

I gave the .project-widget a bottom padding to create the space for the iMac image and the other image on top of the iMac:

```
.project-widget {
        background-color: white;
        padding-top: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 177px;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        box-shadow: -5px -5px 5px -5px #eee, 5px -5px 5px -5px #eee;
    }
```

Using media queries I change the padding as required.

I also positioned the wrapper .project-widget-wrap relative so I can position the images container at the bottom of the widget, using position: absolute on the project-image-container div:

```
.project-widget-wrap {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        position: relative;
    }

.project-image-container {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 177px;
    }

.project-image-container img {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

Any idea how I can style this so the featured image stays inside of the iMac screen image and have it scale to different screen sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a lot of the CSS. You do need a .container around a row or the padding will be off. The thing to do is to find the ratio. I don't know if the images are squares or what, but that's what you had. Otherwise, I suggest that you just make composites. Or just use simple lines around it (draw the "monitor" with borders and shapes), it will look better, less bulky.

## DEMO: http://jsbin.com/lodej/1/

http://jsbin.com/lodej/1/edit

*Another version with the background: http://jsbin.com/lodej/2*

**HTML**:

```
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       
       
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 project-widget-container">
       <section>
          <div class="project-title">
             <h4>Project 1</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="project-excerpt">
             Lorem <a href="#">Test</a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </div>
          <div class="project-image-container">
             <div class="thumb"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://bombdiggitydesign.com/jsbin/xffdfd.png"></div>
             <img class="imac img-responsive" src="http://s29.postimg.org/b5kegwt53/small_mac.png"> 
          </div>
       </section>
    </div>
    <!-- col -->
   
   
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 project-widget-container">
       <section>
          <div class="project-title">
             <h4>Project 1</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="project-excerpt">
             Lorem <a href="#">Test</a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </div>
          <div class="project-image-container">
             <div class="thumb"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://bombdiggitydesign.com/jsbin/xffdfd.png"></div>
             <img class="imac img-responsive" src="http://s29.postimg.org/b5kegwt53/small_mac.png"> 
          </div>
       </section>
    </div>
    <!-- col -->   
   
   <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 project-widget-container">
       <section>
          <div class="project-title">
             <h4>Project 1</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="project-excerpt">
             Lorem <a href="#">Test</a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </div>
          <div class="project-image-container">
             <div class="thumb"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://bombdiggitydesign.com/jsbin/xffdfd.png"></div>
             <img class="imac img-responsive" src="http://s29.postimg.org/b5kegwt53/small_mac.png"> 
          </div>
       </section>
    </div>
    <!-- col -->           

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 project-widget-container">
       <section>
          <div class="project-title">
             <h4>Project 1</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="project-excerpt">
             Lorem <a href="#">Test</a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </div>
          <div class="project-image-container">
             <div class="thumb"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://bombdiggitydesign.com/jsbin/xffdfd.png"></div>
             <img class="imac img-responsive" src="http://s29.postimg.org/b5kegwt53/small_mac.png"> 
          </div>
       </section>
    </div>
    <!-- col -->           
   
   <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
   
 </div>
 <!-- row -->
```

**CSS**

```
.project-widget-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.project-widget-container section {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.project-widget-container section:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    z-index: -1;
}
.project-widget-container section:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: -5px -5px 5px -5px #eee, 5px -5px 5px -5px #eee;
    z-index: -1;
}
.project-title {
    border-left: 2px solid #660061;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.project-title h4 {
    color: #660061;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.project-excerpt {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    height: 60px;
}
img.imac {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.project-image-container {
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;
    padding-top: 85%;
}
.thumb img {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25%;
}
.thumb {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 18%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I just fit it into the actual page and got it to work. In reality I did have a container element around the row, but I just stripped everything down for the fiddle. The images aren't squares, they come in different sizes so I still have to think of something to fix that but I'll probably just render thumbs limiting both width and height. Thanks again, really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a CSS-only iMac then place the image within it...

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9ek3eqmv/10/

```css
.project-widget {
    width:30%;   
    margin:auto;
}
.imac {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:9%;
    margin-bottom:16%;
    border-radius:5px;
    background: #a0a0a0;/* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #a0a0a0 0%, #e0e1e3 100%);/* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #a0a0a0), color-    stop(100%, #e0e1e3));/* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #a0a0a0 0%, #e0e1e3 100%);/* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #a0a0a0 0%, #e0e1e3 100%);/* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #a0a0a0 0%, #e0e1e3 100%);/* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #a0a0a0 0%, #e0e1e3 100%);/* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#a0a0a0', endColorstr='#e0e1e3', GradientType=1);/* IE6-9 */
}
.imac .bezel {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    background-color:black;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
    padding:4.25%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.imac .bezel:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0.25) 0%, rgba(255,252,252,0) 100%);/* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.25)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,252,252,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0.25) 0%,rgba(255,252,252,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0.25) 0%,rgba(255,252,252,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0.25) 0%,rgba(255,252,252,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0.25) 0%,rgba(255,252,252,0) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#40ffffff', endColorstr='#00fffcfc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    top:0%;
    bottom:-20%;
    right:0;
    left:60%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-25deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0% -o-transform: rotate(-25deg);
    -o-transform-origin: 0% 0% transform: rotate(-25deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
.imac .screen {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#444 no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.imac .screen:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 56.25%; /* imac has aspect ratio of 16:9*/
}
.imac .stand {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:-22%;
    width:20%;
    margin:auto;
    background:#ddd;
    background: rgb(141, 142, 146); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(141, 142, 146, 1) 3%, rgba(226, 227, 230, 1) 38%, rgba(244, 244, 244, 1) 51%, rgba(128, 129, 132, 1) 64%, rgba(193, 193, 193, 1) 77%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 95%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(3%, rgba(141, 142, 146, 1)), color-stop(38%, rgba(226, 227, 230, 1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(244, 244, 244, 1)), color-stop(64%, rgba(128, 129, 132, 1)), color-stop(77%, rgba(193, 193, 193, 1)), color-stop(95%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(141, 142, 146, 1) 3%, rgba(226, 227, 230, 1) 38%, rgba(244, 244, 244, 1) 51%, rgba(128, 129, 132, 1) 64%, rgba(193, 193, 193, 1) 77%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 95%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(141, 142, 146, 1) 3%, rgba(226, 227, 230, 1) 38%, rgba(244, 244, 244, 1) 51%, rgba(128, 129, 132, 1) 64%, rgba(193, 193, 193, 1) 77%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 95%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(141, 142, 146, 1) 3%, rgba(226, 227, 230, 1) 38%, rgba(244, 244, 244, 1) 51%, rgba(128, 129, 132, 1) 64%, rgba(193, 193, 193, 1) 77%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 95%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(141, 142, 146, 1) 3%, rgba(226, 227, 230, 1) 38%, rgba(244, 244, 244, 1) 51%, rgba(128, 129, 132, 1) 64%, rgba(193, 193, 193, 1) 77%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 95%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8d8e92', endColorstr='#e0e0e0', GradientType=0); /* IE6-9 */
}
.imac .stand:before, .imac .stand:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:2px;
    height:2px;
    border:10px solid grey;
    border-color:transparent #e0e0e0;
}
.imac .stand:before {
    right:100%;
    border-width:9px 12px 0px 0px;
}
.imac .stand:after {
    left:100%;
    border-width:9px 0px 0px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-widget">    

<div class="imac">
    <div class="bezel">
        <div class="screen" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/250/abstract)" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="stand"></div>
</div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try http://jsfiddle.net/webspilka/oa74zbb6/

Perhaps it requires a java script that would set the height for .project-image-container.height = .imac.height
and

```
img.featured-image {
    max-height: 150px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
 }

$('.project-image-container').outerHeight('setHeightChild.imac')
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it make your job easier if you just made the "imac" image a background image this way you can always get the effect on any size screen with your @media (whatever your adjustments are) CSS. This will also help you eliminate all the padding issues. Here is some mark-up to get you started. Hope this helps you!

```
<!--Your HTML Mark-Up-->
```

```
<div class="project-widget">

  <div class="project-title">
    <h4>Project 2</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="project-excerpt">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </div>

  <!--<div class="project-thumbnail-placeholder"></div>-->

</div>

<div id="project-image-container">
  <!--I removed the "iMac" and replaced it in your background"-->
  <img class="featured-image" src="http://s29.postimg.org/ryb2fc5tz/test_2.jpg">
</div>

</div>

</div>


/* Your CCS */

#project-image-container {
min-width: 255px;
min-height: 177px;
background-image: url("http://s29.postimg.org/b5kegwt53/small_mac.png");
/*Just Place Mac Images as background*/
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.featured-image {
width: 242px;
height: 134px;
padding: 6px;
}

/* You can now adjust this for all your media sized with @media(....)*/
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5cvmjj8z/)